# Where can I find beginner videos for Blender?

Tags: modeling, scripting, export, workflow, edit-mode

The YouTube Channel videos for beginners which start out with hotkeys, and learning the interface are based on an older model of the program, and the location/function of the buttons seem to be outdated.

The purpose for which I am using the program is to create housing and environmental structuring on Second Life.

Can anyone kindly direct me to a location that will guide me through the steps of getting acquainted with the program so that I can begin implementing it, please? Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 1):

Heres the playlist I used, its well done:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrgQj91MOVfjTShOMRY8TLmkJ7OFr7bj6

Answer (score 0):

These are short, to the point, very easy to follow along.

https://vimeo.com/channels/blendervideotutorials/videos/sort:alphabetical/format:thumbnail

Some more here on the blender site but they might be more intermediate.

https://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

To reach your goals in a efficient time I suggest to not only watch videos.

Find yourself someone who would be willing to to teach you blender too.
If you work actively with someone its much more enjoyable and you have someone to ask questions if needed.

Here is a Blender 2.7* Playlist https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY6KPrc4uMw&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS

Answer (score -1):

I find that tutorials are great, but project based tutorials are better. They are better because they leave you with a fantastic result at the end of each one. There are many people who do project based tutorials. [BlenderGuru](http://www.blenderguru.com/) would be a good one to look into when you become more advanced. For now, I would suggest [Tutor4u](https://www.youtube.com/user/tutor4u). His tutorials range in length, but are so easy to understand that you can literally just listen to the audio and work in Blender while it's playing.

Comment: The OP asked "Can anyone kindly direct me to a location that will guide me through the steps of getting acquainted with the program". In this case project based tutorials aren't what the OP is asking for.